# How to automate BrowserStack screenshot API on my localhost?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, automated-tests, browserstack

I tried to go through their [Screenshots API](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api) & [Local testing](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing) but got lost in between.. 
All I want is to test my front-end style guide (language agnostic), can someone direct me to a good direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating screenshots for internal URL via Screenshots API is a two-step process:

a) Setup Local Testing using the BrowserStack Local binary. The command is as follows:
./BrowserStackLocal --key KEY
More details on Local Testing is available [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#modifiers).

b) Add the parameter "local" = true in your Rest API. For more information, [refer](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api#generate-screenshots).

Example for generating a screenshot for localhost on Windows 7-IE 8:

"UserName:KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -d '{"browsers": [{"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"}], "url": "http://localhost", "local": "true"}' https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots

Note: The access key for your account can be acquired from [here](https://www.browserstack.com/accounts/settings).

Comment: I set up something like `./BrowserStackLocal --key MYKEY --enable-logging-for-api` but got lost on the 2nd step. Is there any video tutorial somewhere? all I want is to view screenshots (multiple browsers) of my frontend local components and put them on the guide..